# Send current location through an SMS

Tags: xcode, ios5, gps, sms, location

I'm trying to get my app to be able to send its current GPS location through an SMS to a preentered phone number.

I have my code right now that only brings up an SMS window inside the app in which I can edit in the receiving number and a body. What I am wondering is how I get the current location in this body so it can be sent through the SMS? Can't figure it out.

This is how my code looks right now regarding the SMS function.

```
-(IBAction) sendInAppSMS:(id) sender
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"Alarm!, call the senders number!";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"phonenumber1", @"phonenumber2", nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: use core location framework to get the current location.this can be appended to your sms body

Comment: @Marcus - Were you able to fix this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly add   core location framework in Your Project. and call this method for finding current location.

```
 -(IBAction) sendInAppSMS:(id) sender
    {
        MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
        {
            CLLocation *location=[self findCurrentLocation];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinae=[location coordinate];
            controller.body =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" Alarm!, call the senders number with latitude:%f longitude:%f",coordinae.latitude,coordinae.longitude]; ;
            controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"phonenumber1", @"phonenumber2", nil];
            [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }
    }

-(CLLocation*)findCurrentLocation
           {

            CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            if ([locationManager locationServicesEnabled])
            {
                locationManager.delegate = self; 
                locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; 
                locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
                [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            }

            CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
         return location;

    }
```

Comment: I have added core location framework, and also tried added the code above, it gives me three issues. 1 - 'locationServicesEnabled' is deprecated. 2 - Assigning to 'id<CCLocationManagerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ERSSecondViewController*'. 3 - Unused variable 'coordinate'. Must be missing something.. :P But what code do I need to put in the IBAction sendInAppSMS to then get the coordinates in the sms message? And thanks again for all your help!

Comment: I've fixed the first two issues/errors. But the last one remains that tells me "Unused variable 'coordinate'. But I'm getting there :P

Comment: just comment this line CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];use this where you want to send the coordinate.

Comment: Feeling pretty stupid now :P But where in this code should I put above line? -(IBAction) sendInAppSMS:(id) sender
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = @"Alarm!, call the senders number!";
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"phonenumber1", @"phonenumber2", nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}

Comment: Worked like a charm! now I need to find out how to code it to be able to get it in form of a link in the sms so the receiver just can click on it and it opens in Maps. And somehow now my cancel button doesn't works when I bring up the sendInAppSMS window. But Still I can send.. so thats great! :)

Comment: @MuditBajpai Hi Mudit, I am having some issues with this. Can you please give me your email so that can chat over? Would be happy to connect with you. :) Thanks

Comment: @HelloMobile:my mail id is muditknit02@gmail.com.